# SQL INTO clause in Views

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Is it possible to use INTO clause in views?I tried out it like the one below,

> SELECT [ApplicantId], [KSAId],
>   [Accurate]+[Speed] as 'Score',
>   [TimeCompleted] INTO temp2 FROM Table1
>   WHERE TimeCompleted Is not Null

but it throws me an error, Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'into'.

Comment: you can't use select INTO in the definition of a view, but you can update a view depending upon certain conditions: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187956.aspx

Comment: What RDBMS are you using, the answer here is likely to be different between them, as the support for updatable views differes between them considerably.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

- A view is a SELECT only
- temp2 would have no scope outside of the view
- this is a stored procedure
- ...

Comment: Updateable views means "UPDATE VIEW SET...". Not "SELECT .. INTO ..." inside a view

Comment: I know that. You make the statement "A view is a SELECT only" which could easily be misconstrued.

Comment: `A view is defined by a SELECT statement that must return a rowset`. Somewhat longer but less ambiguous (though I'm quite happy with your version, to be sincere).

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to create a new table based on the select, you should use

```
CREATE TABLE temp2
AS
SELECT .....
```

The SQL Server version of this statement is basically what you already did. Then only thing I noticed is that you are using single quotes for quoting the computed column alias. I think SQL Server complies with the standard here and needs double quotes (or those dreaded square brackets):

```
 SELECT [ApplicantId], 
        [KSAId], 
        [Accurate]+[Speed] as "Score", 
        [TimeCompleted] 
   INTO temp2 
 FROM Table1 
 WHERE TimeCompleted Is not Null
```

If that is not working, then you are not telling us the whole story.

Comment: When I modify the above query in View as you said like, Create Table temp2 AS (SELECT [ApplicantId], [KSAId], [Accurate]+[Speed] as 'Score', [TimeCompleted] INTO temp2 FROM Table1 WHERE TimeCompleted Is not Null) It also shows me the error incorrect syntax near AS

Comment: @Nanda: which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

In what DBMS? Some might make it possible if you define `INSTEAD OF INSERT` trigger.